# override Connection:keep-alive in RPC GWT

Tags: http, gwt, connection, rpc

I want to change default Connection:keep-alive from rpc service to Connection:close
What Im doing is:

```
reqBuilder = new RpcRequestBuilder() {
  @Override
  protected RequestBuilder doCreate(String serviceEntryPoint) {
    RequestBuilder rb = super.doCreate(serviceEntryPoint);
    rb.setHeader("Connection", "close");
    return rb;
  }
};

((ServiceDefTarget) ObjectService).setRpcRequestBuilder(reqBuilder);
```

But. The default Connection:keep-alive is still appearing. (some gwt class is overriding it)
Any Idea?

Comment: Hi.. I just seemed to come across the exact same issue you were speaking about and it is specific to IE 8. Were you able to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Connection` header is managed by the browser. The `setHeader` is a no-op for this header: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#the-setrequestheader-method

Comment: Is there a way to keep connections close in ie8? i'm trying to set response header (Connection:close) from server, but it's seems not useful.